Fact & Dim Table on Dependencies
I have 3 tables I’m trying to build relationships with in PowerBI. Here’s a rough example
Project Details (Fact)

Project ID
Project Manager

Predecessor Details (Dim)

Project ID

Successor Details (Dim)

Project ID

I have a one to many relationship with Project Details and Predecessor Details on Project ID. I also have a one to many relationship with Project Details and Successor Details on Project ID.
In a PowerBI page I want to see the Project Manager of both the Predecessor and Successor dependencies. How would I manage this relationship in PowerBI? I’m currently not able to pull in predecessor and successor table into 1 visual.
Tried to build relationships in PowerBI.

Using Power Query :
Create a new table using  Merge Queries as New where you select the Predecessor Details as the 1st table and Project Details as the 2nd table and join them on Project ID :

Then select the Project Manager column :

You should do the same for Successor Details.
Then create a blank query where you combine both tables and you add a column to specify the dependency type:
= let
    Predecessors = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Query1", {"Project ID", "Project Manager"}),
    PredecessorsWithDependency = Table.AddColumn(Predecessors, "Dependency Type", each "Predecessor"),
    Successors = Table.SelectColumns(#"Merged Query2", {"Project ID", "Project Manager"}),
    SuccessorsWithDependency = Table.AddColumn(Successors, "Dependency Type", each "Successor"),
    CombinedTable = Table.Combine({PredecessorsWithDependency, SuccessorsWithDependency})
in
    CombinedTable


Using DAX :
You can add both CC to each dimension :
Predecessor_ProjectManager = 
LOOKUPVALUE('Project Details'[Project Manager], 'Project Details'[Project ID], 'Predecessor Details'[Project ID])



Successor_ProjectManager = 
LOOKUPVALUE('Project Details'[Project Manager], 'Project Details'[Project ID], 'Successor Details'[Project ID])

Then you create a calculated table to combine your result :
MyTable = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'Predecessor Details',
        "Project ID", 'Predecessor Details'[Project ID],
        "Dependency Type", "Predecessor",
        "Project Manager", 'Predecessor Details'[Predecessor_ProjectManager]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        'Successor Details',
        "Project ID", 'Successor Details'[Project ID],
        "Dependency Type", "Successor",
        "Project Manager", 'Successor Details'[Successor_ProjectManager]
    )
)


From a modeling prespective you may need only one dimension linked to your fact table through a bridge table where you have the Project ID, the manager and the dependency column.
The fact table and the dimension will have 1 to many relationship to your bridge table.
